# Too many rewrite URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have a question about magento 1.9.0.1.

I'm doing the support of an online shop for customers.
Currently, I'm making a search engine optimization. In the analysis I noticed that we have 3643 rewrite URLs in the system.
But we have only 973 Single Products in the system. In addition, the few are used by the Single Products in 57 configurable products.

Could be problems with SEO or the Site speed it might.

It is also interesting that the SEO Alnalysesoftware 265 URLs were analyzed with limited indexing. And 256 with 302 redirect URLs

Comment: How many store views do you have?

Answer (score 0):

System>Configuration>Web
Under **URL Options**
Auto-redirect to Base URL [NO]
If you already have NO selected, then its probably your .htaccess or a CDN.
Also: http or https?